# Return empty URL on failure

Tags: swift, return, closures

In a function like this:

```
func getMessageDetails()->URL{

        if let theLinks = theMessage.links as? [[String:String]]{
            let thisLink = theLinks[3]["Href"]
            let url = URL(string: thisLink)
            return url!
        }
        return nil// is unacceptable, what should I put here?
    }
```

what should I return outside the closure?

Answer (score 3):

In this case the best solution is to return an optional URL, it can also handle the case if the link is not a valid URL. And you should check if the `thisLink` array contains more than 3 items to avoid an out-of-range exception:

```
func getMessageDetails() -> URL? {

    if let theLinks = theMessage.links as? [[String:String]], 
        theLinks.count > 3,
        let thisLink = theLinks[3]["Href"] {
        return URL(string: thisLink)
    }
    return nil
}
```